# compare elements of array of many arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I trying to loop through an array of arrays, and compare the elements with each-other in-order to find the common elements. so lets say if we have `var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,2,5]];` I want to first compare [i][i] and [i+1][i], [i][i+1] and [i+1][i+1] and [i][i+2] and [i+1][i+2] and so on. here is my code:

```
function sym(args) {
  var fullArr = [];
  var finalArr = [];
  // store the arguments inside a single array
  for (var count = 0; count < arguments.length; count ++) {
    fullArr[count] = arguments[count];
  }
  // loop through finalArr[];
  for (var i = 0; i < fullArr.length; i++) {
    if (fullArr[i][i] == fullArr[i++][i++]) {
      // if the element matches (it is a common element)
      // store it inside finalArr
      finalArr[i] = fullArr[i];
    }
  }
  return finalArr;
}

sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

problem: when I run the code instead of an array containing the matching element, I get an empty array

Comment: `fullArr[i++][i++]` isn't doing what you think it is. It's incrementing i *each* time, and it's incredibly bad practice (even when it works) because people reading it can't remember which i gets incremented first, so they're not sure if it means `fullArr[1][2]` or `fullArr[2][1]`

Comment: What about if list 1 was 1,1,2,3 and list 2 was 1,1,1,2,3? How many times should 1 appear in the final output array

Comment: Also you havent specified what to do if there are n arrays....are we just going to pull only values that are common across all three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to iterate over one array and see if the other array includes the value you have specified.

My answer is similar to a nested for loop in that the includes method does exactly that. It takes in as a parameter an element and checks if the array which called it contains said element. In order to do that it must iterate through all elements in the array in the worst case.

My answer also assumes that you only want to count duplicate matches once.

```js
function sym(args) {
  var fullArr = [];
  var finalArr = [];
  // store the arguments inside a single array
  for (var count = 0; count < arguments.length; count ++) {
    fullArr[count] = arguments[count];
  }
  // loop through finalArr[];
  
  //since you are comparing only two arrays in this 
 //example you just have to iterate over each element in the first array aka fullArr[0] and
 //check if each element "e" is also in the second array aka fullArr[1] 
 //AND that your final output array does not already contain it.
 //If both of these are true then we push the element to the output array.
  fullArr[0].forEach(function(e){
       if(fullArr[1].includes(e) && !finalArr.includes(e)) finalArr.push(e);
    
    });
  return finalArr;
}

sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

However if you want to check if a particular element exists in *all* collections of an n length array then I would propose something like this:

```js
function sym(args) {
  var fullArr = [];
  var finalArr = [];
  // store the arguments inside a single array
  for (var count = 0; count < arguments.length; count ++) {
    fullArr[count] = arguments[count];
  }
      
      var newArr = fullArr[0].reduce( function(prev, e1) {
         if(prev.indexOf(e1) < 0 && fullArr.every( function(arr){
                   return arr.indexOf(e1) > -1;
             })){
             return [...prev, e1];    
           }else{
                   return prev;
           };
       },[]);
       alert(newArr);        
       return newArr;
}

sym([1,1, 2, 3,4], [5, 2, 1, 4], [4,1,2, 5]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, when I run your first code I get this error: TypeError: fullArr[1].includes is not a function

Comment: try my second solution with indexof

Comment: Also I still don't know if you want the intersection across n arrays...the way you set up your function it seems that you do.

Comment: ok thanks for the update, sorry to ruin your lunch time. What i'm trying to do is go through the array and find the matching elements. One more thing  could you explain this line  fullArr[0].forEach(function(e){

Comment: yeah the problem proposes multiple arrays so you were right to assume that. any way thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome :-) please feel free to mark an answer as helpful if you find it to be!

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski I tested your second solution by providing the following parameters `sym([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1], [5, 2, 1, 4], [4, 1, 2, 5]);` and it appears that your solution does not account for duplicate values in arrays - when I ran your code with the above input, I got the following output: `[1, 2, 4, 1, 1]`

Comment: @Vlad Z Valid point! My last edit which I thought made my answer more efficient actually also had the bug which you noticed. Changed the answer to a reduce function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the first array and check if any of its values are common through all the other arrays.

```
function sym() {
    var common = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arguments[0].length; i++) {
        var isCommon = common.indexOf(arguments[0][i]) === -1; // first check if its not already exists in the common array
        for (var j=1; j<arguments.length && isCommon; j++) {
            isCommon = arguments[j].indexOf(arguments[0][i]) > -1
        }
        if (isCommon) common.push(arguments[0][i])
    }
    return common;
}
```

of course you can improve it by iterating over the smallest array.

Comment: @naortor could you please explain what is happening at this line:  for (var j=1; j<arguments.length && isCommon; j++) { thanks

Comment: @zamzam - in that loop i'm looping through all the other arrays and check if the arguments[0][i] value is in all of them - if I found one array that arguments[0][i] value isn't in it - there is no point in keep looping. lt;dr loop through all the other array while isCommon is true.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when the following line executes, you also increment the value of `i` which is your control variable:

`if (fullArr[i][i] == fullArr[i++][i++])`

Thus, this is how your `i` variable gets incremented in each iteration:

**Iteration #1:** `i = 0`

**Iteration #2:** `i = 3`
 - you get i+2 from the line that I mentioned above, +1 more from the increment that you specify in the final condition of the for loop

Therefore, even after the first iteration, your function will return an empty array on your particular scenario, as you are passing an array of length 3, and the for loop ends after `i = 0` on the first iteration.

Even if the loop would go on, it would return an index out of bounds exception because your array of length 3 would not have an `array[3]` element.

For example, if you want to compare just two arrays, as in your scenario, you need to loop through each of them and compare their elements:

```
function sym(array1, array2) {
  var results = [];


  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
          if(array1[i] === array2[j]) {
              if(results.indexOf(array1[i]) === -1) {
                  results.push(array1[i]);
              }
          }
      }
  }

  return results;
}

sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

I have also built a solution that returns the intersection of the arrays that you provide as the parameters for the function, regardless of how many arrays there are:

```
function sym(args) {
    var paramSet = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var counterObject = {};
    var results = [];

    paramSet.forEach(function (array) {
        // Filter the arrays in order to remove duplicate values
        var uniqueArray = array.filter(function (elem, index, arr) {
            return index == arr.indexOf(elem);
        });


        uniqueArray.forEach(function (element) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(counterObject, element)) {
                counterObject[element]++;
            } else {
                counterObject[element] = 1;
            }
        });
    });


    for (var key in counterObject) {
        if (counterObject[key] === paramSet.length) {
            results.push(parseInt(key));
        }
    }

    return results;

}

sym([1, 2, 3, 3, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [1, 7, 9, 10]);
```

The above code will return `[1]` for the example that I provided, as that is the intersection of all 3 arrays.

Comment: This will result in duplicate matches (Im assuming we dont want any) if in the second list an element appears more than once and matches only one element in the first list.

Comment: Indeed - thank you for pointing that out. I have now fixed my code to account for possible duplicates.

Comment: close ....but now the problem is that if the 1 appears more than once in any of the arrays it will disappear from the result set. Also, if 1 appeared twice in the second array, for instance, and 0 times in the third array then your implementation would still have it in the result set.

Comment: You are correct, thank you for the feedback. I have fixed my code in order not to mislead anyone who might read my answer - I tested it and works as it should.